# Unable to Setup Jenkins (Cloudbees)

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to install Jenkins on my Tomcat 9 server. I downloaded the war file and got it deployed. It gave a whole lot of std out on the console, but at this stage I am new to Jenkins so don't know if they are errors or something expected. I have my Tomcat configured to use SSL port (8443). I got Jenkins deployed and I opened Jenkins, but after selecting the standard plugins, I get an error:

```
An error occurred during installation: No such plugin: cloudbees-folder
```

The only change I did before this was in the `hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml`, changed the URL from:

```
<url>https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json</url>
```

to

```
<url>http://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json</url>
```

Comment: I just wanted to add, I tried manually selecting the plugins, it happens on the next plugin as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it turned out to be a proxy issue! Since I was on my office network. What I did was:

1. Delete the Jenkins folder from Tomcat's webapps folder.
2. Delete all folders related to Jenkins.
3. Then redeploy Jenkins.war again.
4. This time when starting Jenkins, it gave me an error saying "It seems Jenkins is Offline" or something on those lines, and an option to setup a proxy, which I did and it installed all the plugins without any hassle!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried with both the url's it works for me .
may be you can try to update from Jenkins UI . Go to
Manage Jenkins --> Manage Plugins --> Advanced
You can see Update site field and check whether your url is updated or not , you can chagne the url from here easily and also you can click on check now button to get the update information